# How can I hide the last row from each group?

Tags: crystal-reports

Using VB 6 and Crystal Report 8.5, how can I hide the last row from each group? Do I need to use a Crystal Report formula? I don't want to display a last row from the each group.

How can I write this formula, and where should I write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a group for the field that you want it grouped by and then use the following formula in the suppress formula (x+2) on the details section in the Section Expert.

Below is an example assuming the report is grouped by user.

```
if OnLastRecord then
    true
else
    {Test;1.user} <> next({Test;1.user})
```

The first part will hide the last row since there is no row to compare against and the else part will evaluate each row and compare it with the next row.

Comment: Glad to see this helped me today, in 2018 after 9 years!

Comment: @Dusty How can I hide the first row from each group?

Comment: @ShreyasPednekar I apologize, but I haven't used Crystal Reports in quite some time. I'd assume that you could do a running total to count the number of rows for a group and hide each row where that total is equal to 1 instead of trying to use a method like this. Hope this helps.